# Backup and easy USB restoration for XP

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, usb, backup

I have 6 networks. Two(2) to ten(10) PCs on each network that need to have the ability to restore from a crashed HDD with minimal downtime.  They are mission critical machines.  On going backups are not needed only the ability to restore to original image state.

Currently I've inherited a system that uses Ghost 32 (version from 2001 or so) to do backups of workstations, then put the backup on a bootable USB stick that is left with each machine.

The idea is that if we have a HDD crash, someone can go off to the workstation, swap out the HDD, plug in the USB stick and turn it on.  Wait while it automatically boots-and-restores the HDD image and we're good to go.

The advantages of this is that each machine has it's own USB stick with its own fully configured and ready to go image and there is no need for network connectivity.  Any monkey could go in and swap out the HDD and insert a USB.  No user interaction required besides removing the USB at the end.  No configurations needed as its all been done prior to imaging.  Workstation up and running inside of 15 minutes and it's like nothing every happened.

The bootable USB is based on Hiren's Mini-XP.

Problem is we're getting newer PCs and Mini-XP doesn't play nice.  Ghost 11.0 is so friggin' old it makes me think of the 80's so I'd kinda like to change it to something newer.

What solution do you folks use for a rapid restore of a crashed HDD that is network isolated?

Comment: Do the newer systems still need to run XP? Most of the better options run windows 7.

Comment: Something to think about:  Depending on the network speeds and setup, you could use drbl from drbl.sourceforge.net to provide network booting.  Turn on PC hit F12 a couple times and it starts re-imaging.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **unetbootin** to make a USB stick bootable from the **clonezilla** ISO.

After **unetbootin** is done with the USB stick, you can boot a PC with the master image and capture it on the USB stick.

Then make copies of the USB stick.

**You would have to modify the start up script to make it run automatically.**

Answer (score 1):

Ghost is old but unfortunately working decently well for the job.

If you have access to Ghost Console (not just the ghost.exe) you can use it to create DOS-based ISO (or bootable USB) which will boot DOS, run Ghost, and you can even script it so running ghost will automatically image the machine.

An idea: Rather than doing it on the Client PC (where it is newer and Hiren MiniXP doesn't work so well) - if you have an older, dedicated machine you can use (that Hiren MiniXP still works, and you don't feel like changing the system... yet), why not do the imaging at your end (and shutdown the PC afterwards), take out the HDD and then simply go to the client PC, and swap the HDD, and its ready to go (so client won't even see the imaging process, you just come in with a new HDD, swap, and done - the user will only have about 5 minutes downtime for physical HDD swap, and however long time your OS need to boot up for the first time).

Another idea: If you have the funds and allowed to keep spare HDD, why not pre-image HDD with the correct workstation name/number, so any crashes at the client side, swap HDD (no waiting time). It does means you must have as much HDD as the client PCs (10 spare HDD sitting doing nothing) but this does means you got as close to zero downtime.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Macrium reflect is a very good program to replace ghost for Windows 7 machines - Try with the free edition but you must purchase as you have a few computers. Reflect also has a PE compatible version which can be run from the USB stick once you have booted the Hiren Mini-XP.